# Unable to connect to MSN network with Adium

Tags: macos, networking, firewall, windows-live-messenger

I'm new to the Mac world and tried both MSN Messenger for Mac (7.0 and 8.0 beta) as well as Adium to connect to the Windows network. I've enable 'Allow all incoming connections' in the Firewall settings. Windows Live Messenger works fine when connecting through the same router on my Windows laptop.  I've triple checked my password and verified it through a web browser and Windows Live.

Any ideas what my issue could be?

Comment: What error/result do you get?

Comment: It notifies me that it was unable to connect to the server and to verify that I am connect to the internet. There is a cancel and a retry button. No error code...

Comment: there are two good log places to look for errors, then. The Adium itself have a debug panel, and there's the **Console** (just look for it on spotlight).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adium have always worked fine for connecting with MSN, but MSN protocols keep changing. Without further info, since it's not firewall issues, it's most likely that you have an **outdated Adium**.

Comment: I downloaded it right from the Adium website and tried it and experienced this issue :\

Comment: @Adam I'm currently with 1.4b17 apparently built in December 2th, 2009 o_O anyway, I just tried, and it's working. So it's sure to be something on your end, and if it is really not the firewall or anything external to Adium, its got to be your installation.